# How can I reset accumulator of scan on ReplaySubject?

Tags: rxjs, reactivex, subject

I have a `ReplaySubject` that accumulate data with `scan` operator and every 10000 ms should be reset. Is there any another way to do it?

Now:

```
let subject = new ReplaySubject();

subject.scan((acc, cur) => {
            acc.push(cur);
            return acc;
        }, [])
        .subscribe(events => {
            localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(events))
        });

subject
    .bufferTime(10000)
    .map(() => {
        subject.observers[0]._seed = [];
    })
    .subscribe(() => localStorage.removeItem('data'));
```

Answer (score 4):

I asked a very similar question few days ago and later answered myself

[accumulating values such as with scan but with the possibility to reset the accumulator over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50017047/accumulating-values-such-as-with-scan-but-with-the-possibility-to-reset-the-accu/50018313#50018313)

maybe this can help you

SOME MORE DETAILS

An alternative approach is to have an Observable which acts as a **timer** which emits at a fixed interval, 10000ms in your case.

Once this **timer** emits, you pass the control to the Observable that cumululates via `scan` operator. To pass the control you use the `switchMap` operator to make sure the previous instance of the Observable completes.

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve, I would use a normal Subject rather than ReplaySubject.

The code could look something like this

```
const subject = new Subject<number>();

const timer = Observable.timer(0, 1000).take(4);

const obs = timer.switchMap(
    () => {
        console.log('-----');
        return subject
            .scan((acc, cur) => {
                acc.push(cur);
                return acc;
            }, []);
    }
)

obs.subscribe(
    events => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(events))
    }
);


// TEST DATA EMITTED BY THE SUBJECT
setTimeout(() => {
    subject.next(1);
}, 100);
setTimeout(() => {
    subject.next(2);
}, 1100);
setTimeout(() => {
    subject.next(3);
}, 2100);
setTimeout(() => {
    subject.next(4);
}, 2200);
```